# How to configure Cookies with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to configure `Cypress` to have a `Cookie` in each request `header`. How do I achieve this? I'm trying this way:

```js
it('successfully loads', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200', { headers: { Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=064063D96094773DACBD93A2FD31736F' } });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`cy.setCookie()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie#Syntax) method.

**Usage ✅:**

```js
cy.setCookie('auth_key', '123key') // Set the 'auth_key' cookie to '123key'
```